# Time complexity of the program with recursion and loop

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What is the time complexity when f is called based on a loop limit that is variable?

Example code:

```
def rec(i,j,k,n):
 for h in range(1,j):
    f(i,j,k,h)// function call O(1)
 if k<=n:
    rec(i+1,j+i+1,k+j+1,n)
 else:
    pass
```

Program called with i=0,j=0,k=0 and passing n

```
rec(0,0,0,n)
```

Comment: Please show what you've attempted. Homeworks dumps are not welcome here.

Comment: I don't see a question here. Please explain in which step you need help.

Comment: How does one manage to find the time complexity when f is called based on a loop limit that is variable?

Answer (score 1):

`i` grows linearly with the call depth.
`j` integrates `i`, and so grows quadratically with call depth
`k` integrates `j`, and so grows cubicly with call depth.

The maximum depth reached is therefore **ϴ(n^(1/3))**

There are also **ϴ(n^1/3)** calls with depth > **n^1/3 / 2**, which dwarf the other calls.

These calls each take **ϴ(n^2/3)** time in the loop, so the final complexity is **ϴ(n^1/3 * n^2/3) = ϴ(n)**

So this is pretty tricky, but it takes linear time.   You should really do an experiment to make sure, though.